# Vue3 composable with render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, composable, vue-render-function

Is it possible to create a composable function that would use render function so it can display something?

Example:

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

export function useErrorHandling() {
  return {
    render() {
        return h('div', { class: 'bar', innerHTML: 'world!' })      
    }
  }
}
```

```
<script setup>
import { useErrorHandling } from './mouse.js'

 useErrorHandling()
</script>

<template>
 hello
</template>
```

[plaground with above example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kUFvgzAMhf9KlgutVOCOqkk7TOphu+2YCwVTUhEncgKdhPjvc4CiaZ0qLtjP+uz3Mso357KhB1nIo69IuyA8hN69KtTGWQpiFL2HdyJLpxLrTuNFTKIha0SS5caymF19olDhw+Bur/CYL1gGchHAuK4MwJVooetsHNia8iCXpakpHVMt8lkjjwq1Cl7JQsyd2OO7Y61kG4LzRZ77popmrj6zdMn5L6MegzaQgTfpmezNAzFYycMvRs7NASglwBoI6Bnzz+gDN2InhRNbuWfDHrYo2y07Rs6hwfcsNT1WQdv/Mlz8Er8K4d37sn/RVIjfqre7pNZDcuBdVVd6X4jkXBLXGhHo9PX5wZ2bpa5+ScS0jyxOYWby2evt0w/o47jX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes It is possible to do that you need just store the value returned  by the composable in a variable and use it as a component

```
const err =  useErrorHandling()
//in template 
// <err />
```

[Playground Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UcFuwjAM/RUvl4IEzb3qJu0wicN22zGX0hpa1DiRk8Ik1H+f0wJCY0I9NH4vfvZ7Oat37/PjgKpQZai58xECxsG/GeqsdxzhDEPAD2bHm4qavqM9jLBjZyHLtXVC5oeQGTJUOwoRkBle4aFpsTRU6nmEiEsR0fq+iigVtNj3Tv5QpnYtUKnveENqpeZ91rbyMtCRbHxOHeZCBKMKmJCEiaVUG9XG6EOhddjVyech5I73Wk45DxQ7izkGu96yOwVkETZqdaehBTwirxmpQUZ+pvnn6oNukh0NjWLlGpt4uKXc3mIVySlP/Jmo3UB17Bz9E+nsl+XBmK7e5/kzZ2L6Lny7yJrumK1kVt1XIRSQbSuWuiNC3nx/fQpyctw3LxmMy6QlKUyasvZl9/EXJGLBlA==)

Comment: Aha, thanks. It's not possible to show something (for example teleported to body toast) without the component instance?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to get an instance of the component and append the toast component to it. You can do that by making a reference to the root component using ref or using getCurrentInstance from the internal API. Here is a [demo](https://cutt.ly/iCzmlqG), but I'm not sure if it's a good practice or not 

Answer (score 0):

createApp and mount can help you.

```js
function HelloWorld({ fontSize }) {
  return h(
    'div',
    {
      style: {
        color: 'red',
        fontSize,
      },
    },
    'Hello World'
  )
}
const app2 = createApp(HelloWorld, {
  fontSize: '30px',
})
app2.mount('#app-2') // pass selector you want to mount
```